# IF with nested AND/OR issue

Tags: sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, operators

I'm having a problem with a procedure I wrote, I recently made a change but not sure if this is causing the problem or not where the procedure wont run anything within the IF statement.

The original code was like below and worked fine:

```
IF vPlayerID = 0 THEN
```

I have since changed it to and it's not working:

```
IF ((vPlayerID = 0 AND pNewPlayer = 0) OR (pNewPlayer = 1)) THEN
```

The change is to account for two different scenarios when the procedure is processing, I know I can do something along the lines of `IF (condition OR condition) THEN` just unsure if the above with the AND/OR is correct.

I haven't been able to find anything online regarding this, maybe due to my ignorance as to what I should be searching for, I've tried IF operators and IF conditional statements but not bring me back anything of use. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
vPlayerID: Can be an numeric value from 0+
pNewPlayer: Will always be 0 or 1
```

If pNewPlayer = 1 then if should go into the IF statement always, but if pNewPlayer is 0 then its also dependent on vPlayerID being zero.

Comment: We can't tell if it's correct if you don't tell us what it's supposed to do. Post some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry about that I've added more detailed data.

Comment: Your `IF` statement is correct based on how you describe the logic.